# How to validate RelaxNG syntax?

Tags: xml, relaxng

This is hard to Google since RelaxNG is used to validate other stuff and I am getting too many erroneous results. What I am looking for is a good way to validate that my RelaxNG file itself is free of syntactical errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Standard itself contains a "RelaxNG schema for RelaxNG" - you can validate your schema against this to test its validity using your favourite validator (e.g. Jing).

The Standard (ISO/IEC 19757-2) can be downloaded free-of-charge from:

http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html

Answer (score 3):

You can validate it against the published relaxng schema under:

http://relaxng.org/relaxng.rng

Accessible via http://relaxng.org/#schemas. In case you use xmllint, you can validate your schema like this:

```
$ xmllint --valid --relaxng relaxng.rng myschema.rng
myschema.rng validates
```